# How to count number of columns which are not empty

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like the following one:
[image]

I need to add columns that will include the following:

1. Number of job{i}_start_year columns which are not empty at the end of each row
2. Number of edu{i}_start_year columns which are not empty at the end of each row

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with filter columns names by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), if necessary replace empty strigns to missing values, so possible forward filling missing values per rows by `ffill` and select last column by position in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.assign(job = df.filter(regex='job\d').replace('',np.nan).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1],
          edu = df.filter(regex='edu\d').replace('',np.nan).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1])
```

Comment: @jezrael thank you very much for the feedback, but I got an error telling 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'. Can you suggest a way to overcome this error as well?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want extra columns at the end of each row with the number of non-empty years in the job and edu categories. Try:

```
job_columns= ['job1_start_year','job2_start_year','job3_start_year']
edu_columns = ['edu1_start_year', 'edu2_start_year','edu3_start_year']

df['job_count'] = df[job_columns].ne('').sum(axis = 1).values
df['edu_count'] = df[edu_columns].ne('').sum(axis = 1).values
```